# Audio Skipping while Playing Music

Tags: audio, stock-android, connection-issues, nexus-6p

I just recently encountered a problem with my Nexus 6p where my music (and audio but haven't tested that yet) started Skipping beats and stuttering while I was playing it. This is something new and wasn't happening before. I restarted my phone but it still stuttered. My internet is fine too and this problem is true with all apps including Google play music, Pandora, and Spotify. Are there any fixes for this?

System: Android 6.0.1
Carrier: Google Project Fi
(Phone is not rooted)
(Front facing speakers)

Comment: I would suggest trying to play a local file (push some mp3 file to the phone via Android File Transfer and play it using Play Music) to rule out network problems. In case the problem persists, you can enable Developer Options menu (http://www.greenbot.com/article/2457986/how-to-enable-developer-options-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html) and take a bug report while your music is playing to get some insight into what is happening.

Comment: Could it be related to this issue? (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219725#makechanges)

Comment: It might. After updating my device to the newest security patch it was resolved however.

Answer (score 0):

I had an ongoing and frustrating experience with audio skipping and the "sdcard unexpectedly removed" fault.  I disabled programs, kept my screen open, got a faster card etc.  I should say here that my audio was not on the sdcard, it is in the phone memory.  I hunted through my settings time and again, and finally I came across something in the developer options.  The option to force apps to ask for access to the sdcard was checked.  I unchecked that option and presto!, both my problems went away.  Also, I should say that no app ever asked for permission to access the sdcard.